# How to obtain pose of a mesh that I added as a collision object?

Tags: ros, moveit, tf2, collision-object, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to obtain pose of a collision object that I added to the scene.

I have two nodes (`node1` and `node2`), I also have a launch file which launches a custom world.

`node1` does all the planning and collision checking stuff. Works well

`node2` is to spawn a part into my custom world and attach it to a link(not a manipulator link). I'm using planning_scene_interface to add a mesh collision object to the scene and  also updating the collision between the link and the part using `setEntry()` for `allowedCollisionMatrix`.  I am then using using `planning_scene_monitor` to publish the updates into the scene. All this works well.

Now, in the `node1` I want to obtain the pose of the collision object that I added from `node2`.
I found that I can use `move_group/monitored_planning_scene` topic to get the information of the complete scene. From [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/356183/how-to-use-the-planning-scene-monitor-in-c/) answer I read that `move_group/monitored_planning_scene` topic publish msgs only if there is a change in the scene or if we explicitly make a service request to update the scene and get information out of it.

My question is how do I access the pose of a collision object after making that request? do I need to write a subscriber and callback for the `move_group/monitored_planning_scene` topic to read the pose information?

EDIT: I tried making a `planning_scene_monitor->requestPlanningSceneState("/get_planning_scene")` to get a response on `move_group/monitored_planning_scene` topic, msgs are being published on the topic whenever I make a request, but those msgs does not show the information of the added collision object.

My end goal for getting this pose information is to transform this pose using a transformation_matrix to rotate and/or translate this collision object from `node1` itself.

Is this the right way of doing it? or is there a more straight-forward way to read the pose of the collision object? I see there is a topic being published `/collision_object`, does this topic publish any useful information that I'm trying to find? I don't see anything being published to it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368076/how-to-obtain-pose-of-a-mesh-that-i-added-as-a-collision-object?/) by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get the pose of the collision objects by making a service request to `/get_planning_scene`. Added code snippet below.

```
  get_planning_scene_client = collision_nh_.serviceClient<moveit_msgs::GetPlanningScene>("/get_planning_scene");
  moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene_;
  moveit_msgs::GetPlanningScene srv; 
  srv.request.components.components = moveit_msgs::PlanningSceneComponents::WORLD_OBJECT_GEOMETRY;

  if (get_planning_scene_client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_INFO("Got planning scene from move group.");
    planning_scene_ = srv.response.scene;
  }
  else
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to get planning scene from move group.");
  }

  geometry_msgs::Pose CollisionObjectMeshPose = planning_scene_.world.collision_objects[0].mesh_poses[0];
  std::cout << CollisionObjectMeshPose << std::endl;
```

---

Originally posted by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) with karma: 32 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0